# force stopping of a preloaded app on kyocera rise

Tags: ram, system-apps, force-stop

Can i press force stop on preloaded app on device by pressing on force stop? Would it free internal memory by doing so? i realize that the preloaded device apps cannot b uninstalled however If i wanted to release memory on my internal drive would i be able to stop the app n its programs from running on a permanent basis if i press "force stop" on the preloaded apps which i hv absolutely no use for?

Comment: What should that help? Killing apps is not for saving RAM (rather it's for stopping misbehaving apps running havoc). You might better check if you can *disable* it in the same place, so it does no longer get started automatically.

Answer (score 2):

No, **Force stop** doesn't stop the app running again. It just interrupts it if it's running right now. It doesn't free up any internal storage. It doesn't make any difference to RAM usage: Android will already kill background processes to free up RAM when it needs to, without you pressing **Force stop**.

As Izzy suggests, try pressing **Disable** if you're running a recent enough Android version to have that button: it's on the **App info** screen, right next to **Force stop**. (You might first have to **Uninstall updates**.) This will remove the system app from the app drawer, stop it running completely, and stop it being updated. If you're on an older Android version, you can uninstall the app completely only if you root the device and use a third-party app to do so.